# Building a graph with minimal local average clustering coefficient

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Say I am given `n` vertices and `m` edges.
I aim to build a connected undirected graph with minimal average [local clustering coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient).
Are there any algorithms that build such a graph? How would such an algorithm work?

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by _minimal average local clustering coefficient_?

Comment: @shapiroyaacov Probably the minimal average [local clustering coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient).

Comment: Exactly right, Nico, @shapiroyaacov.

Comment: Do you have any guarantees on the size of m in relation to n?

Comment: For m < 4*((n/4)^2), you can allocate your vertices to 4 clusters A,B,C,D, and for every pair of vertices where one is in A and one in B, or B&C or C&D or D&A, have an edge. This gets a coefficient of zero.

Comment: A general greedy algorithm might work as follows: Find any pair of vertices that are not adjacent to a common vertex and connect them until this is not possible any more. After that, find the vertex pair whose common neighbors have maximal average degree and connect them. It's quite tricky to implement it efficiently and I'm not sure if it will find the optimal solution.

Comment: No @DaveGalvin, but complexity is no real issue.